# How to use date picker in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm using date picker in redux form. I want to show only year. But while posting data year field is going NULL in database.

Can anyone help me.

This is my code :

```
const renderDatePicker = ({input, placeholder, defaultValue, meta: {touched, error} }) => (
  <div>
        <DateTimePicker {...input} format={"YYYY"} selected={input.value ? moment(input.value) : null} time={false} initialView={"decade"} finalView={"decade"} />
    {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
  </div>
);

<Field name="year" component={renderDatePicker} />
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you use this function in redux form?

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass all props to DateTimePicker props in the correct way. I don't know how is working DateTimePicker component, but when you do

```
<DateTimePicker **{...input}** format={"YYYY"} selected={input.value ?
moment(input.value) : null} time={false} initialView={"decade"}
finalView={"decade"} />
{touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
```

Into DateTimePicker has to assign redux-form input to its input prop, else always you will get null in that case. Also you can check in redux-form with property function 'validate' every time when you change that value you should see it.

edit:

I was looking for some issues like this, because I have to do something looked like in DatePicker for React-Native, in that case we don't have input but I have used in this way:

```
    <Field name="birthday"
       component={ props =>
          <DatePicker
            date={props.input.value}
            onDateChange={(date) => props.input.onChange(moment(new Date(date)).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))}
          />
   }/>
```

It's not best way, but this solution could help your case.

Comment: Value is not going to action creator.